# How to set MySQLdb Connection timeout to infinity in python

Tags: python, mysql

I am doing some task on database after every 10 hours . I have connected to database only one time at the start of the script. after 10 hours database connection gets timeout.
I can use other method here but i want to know that how to set Connection timeout to infinity . After 10 hours i am getting an error which is given below .

**Code:**

```
import MySQLdb,time

db = MySQLdb.connect("hostname", "user", "password", "db_name")

while True:
    db.commit() # to refresh database
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("some query here") 
    db.commit()
    cursor.close() 
    time.sleep(36000)# Wait for 10 hours
```

**Error**

> OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the connection is closed from the db server side, what you have to do is;

- Changing the timeout of mysql
  Or more usefull
- Just reconnect to the db again in your loop

If you use linux you can use [cron](https://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/) to launch your script every X sec, if you use windows use the scheduling task service to launch the script when you desire.

Answer (score 0):

From documents, there are two timeouts. one is `write_timeout` and another is `connect_timeout`

connect_timeout - Timeout before throwing an exception when connecting.

> (default: 10, min: 1, max: 31536000)

write_timeout – The timeout for writing to the connection in seconds

> (default: None - no timeout)

From my understanding you need to use connect_timeout.

Hope this helps! Cheers!